# Change a Button Image in Objective C while progressing through a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, uibutton

I am looking for ideas on changing an image of a UIButton as a method progresses after it's pressed, similar to a progress bar but instead this simply will change the button image,and pause to see the image, proceed, change the button image, pause to see the new image, proceed, and then complete on the final image. I'm a bit new to Objective C so any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, the method that you want to display progress for needs to be executing off of the main thread (or the UI will not update).  When you have that set up, all you need to do is configure your background method to call some method on the main thread to report its current status.  That main-thread method can then take the status information and apply any UI updates that you want.

So the important points are:

- Any long-lived method needs to execute in the background so that the UI can continue to update.
- To track progress, periodically call the main thread from the background thread.
- Perform all of your UI updates from the main thread only.

Comment: The method isn't that long lived. In fact, it's short which is why I am having the issue. My method is really quick... I just want to make it look long... you know... fool the boss about how hard this process really is.

Comment: @BFBC - So still do everything as described above, and then add some `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` calls to your background method.  Basically your pattern becomes `[call UI update method] -> [sleep] -> [call UI update method] -> [sleep] -> ...`.  Just repeat until enough time has passed for whatever your purposes are.

Comment: I've got the concept perfectly now and have implemented the code but the ui update method is where it's messing up. I just cannot seem to make that work. ex:[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

Comment: sorry... but I ever time I try to update the ui between the sleep and UIImage commands, it doesn't work. The UIUpdate is killing me... I really feel stupid here

Comment: @BFBC - What if you add a method like `- (void)setImageTo: (NSString*) image` which calls `[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image] forState: UIControlStateNormal];`, and then do something like `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImageTo:) withObject:@"image1.png" waitUntilDone:NO]; [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; ...`?

Comment: So the big issue is updating the image from the action method without leaving the action method.

Comment: @BFBC - You can't do that as far as I know.  The action method is called by the GUI thread (i.e. the main thread).  This is the same thread that is responsible for updating and redrawing the UI.  So there is simply no way for the UI to update until the action method returns because the action method is, in essence, blocking the thread.  The only way for it to work is to have the action method spawn a background thread that calls back to the main thread to perform the updates.  If you need to prevent other things from happening while this runs, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you so much for sticking with me on this. I was hoping someone would have the magic bullet solution to force the thread to refresh prior to completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `buttonType` `Custom`(not RoundRect). and set its `BackgroundImage`. In those methods which you are talking about just change the `BackgroundImage` and it will work.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you.  The button and it's attributes are set... it's just the change and delay I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
[btn_h setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btn_h setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [btn_h setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Regards,
Shyam parmar

Comment: I'm sorry wasn't clear enough. I know how to change the image, I just cannot make it display the change until the method is through. I want it to display the change, pause, proceed, display the new image, pause, proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grand Central Dispatch to run the processing on a separate thread, then dispatch_sync with the main thread to update the UI. This is very easy to do and GCD is extremely fast.

Comment: Thanks,  don't know much about it but am starting to read now.

Answer (score 0):

To change the image for the selected state you have to call setImage for state UIControlStateSelected. You can set separate images for different states (Normal, Highlighted, Disabled, Selected, etc).